# Are there other instances of agni-pariksha in vedic scriptures?

Tags: puranas, rituals, agni, itihasa

We all know the famous agni-pariksha of Srimati Sita Devi from Sri Valmiki Ramayana, so I was wondering are there any other instances of Agni-pariksha described in vedas, puranas or itihasas?